# Firebase analytics doesn't send events

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I want add `Firebase Analytics` to my app, but my events doesn't send to firebase console.

Sending event in code:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "screenName");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("open_screen", params);
```

Console:
[image]

Why my events are not sending?

**ADD_1**:

```
public class AnalyticsManager {

private final String NAME = "name";
private final String OPEN_SCREEN = "open_screen";

private static AnalyticsManager instance;
private final static Object mLock = new Object();

private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

private AnalyticsManager() {
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(Constants.AppContext);
}

public static void start() {
    getInstance();
}

public static AnalyticsManager getInstance() {

    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AnalyticsManager();
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

public void onOpenScreen(String screenName) {

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(NAME, screenName);

    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(OPEN_SCREEN, params);
}
```

}

Comment: How frequently are you seeing dashboard? as per google, documentation _You can view aggregated statistics about your events in the Firebase console dashboards. These dashboards update periodically throughout the day. For immediate testing, use the logcat output as described in the previous section._

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I testing this in Friday, 23 September, but I still dont see events in console

Comment: Is your `mFirebaseAnalytics` is connected ? like `mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);`

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain yes, I make all steps from FBase tutorial

Comment: Try to use `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC` and check your console for output

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I don't know how it can help, but in terminal after entering your commands I see this: Connecting to remote service
Service connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}

Comment: That's it. Your connection to analytics not establishing. Probably you have wrong credentials for analytics

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain ok, thank you, I will search. But in Firebase Plugin I see - all ok http://joxi.ru/LmGV1RVhRVkL6r

Comment: Where are you using this `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);` in your code. its better if you share you code

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain added

Comment: how are you calling this class `AnalyticsManager` ? Where are you calling this class ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain in onCreate() in MainActivity. AppContext - not null, I check this in debug

Comment: Show me how are you using this class.

Comment: How can `context` be in `Constants` ? Change your singleton so it accept instance on the constructor and pass it to firebase

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics uses Google Play Services to work properly.
That's why your message from consosle: `ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}`means that you should update Google Play Services on your phone to have ability to use Firebase.